# Sampling from an infinite population

Tags: normal-distribution, poisson-distribution, central-limit-theorem, astronomy

**SAMPLE SIZE**

I am sampling astronomical data and measuring clusters of galaxies (within a range of 100 megaprsecs) as nodes in a complex network, where `k` is a metric for connected nodes.

`k` distribution has the moments:

1. mean = 2.3
2. median = 2.0
3. mode = 2.0
4. var:  2.3
5. skew:  0.65
6. kurt:  0.42

---

**POISSON DISTRIBUTION**

Histogram of sampled data:

[image]

---

**POPULATION**

But my i.i.d. random variables are from only 3.000 nodes, which seems like nothing in the big scheme of things of the observable universe, which has 14.26 gigaparsecs (46.5 billion light-years or 4.40×1026 m) in any direction.

---

**CENTRAL LIMIT THEOREM**

Also, the Central Limit Theorem (CLT) states that the sample mean of a sufficiently large number of i.i.d. random variables is approximately normally distributed. The larger the sample, the better the approximation.

---

**INFINITE POPULATION**

According to state of the art measurements, however, the universe appears to be not only large enough, but *actually infinite*, because beyond the boundaries of the observable universe, spacetime *itself* is expanding *faster than the speed of light*, so light from galaxies (and their data) traveling from over that distance, will never reach us.

---

**QUESTION**

How large should my sample size be so it is a better proportion of an infinite population, and when should the distribution becomes normally distributed?

Comment: It is not clear to me what all this astronomical information has to do with the actual question!

Comment: in order to contextualize the size of the sample.

Comment: The point is that it doesn't matter: as you just wrote, the *sample size* affects the precision of estimates, not the population size (at least not until the sample is an appreciable proportion of the population).

Comment: If you have something that is distributed Poisson with mean 2.3, it won't take many samples before the distribution of the sample mean will be well-approximated by a Normal distribution.   Of course, "well-approximated" is in the eye of the beholder, but I would think that for most practical purposes a sample size of 25 would do it.

Comment: @jbowman 25? how much is 25 bigger than the size in the question? sorry i am new to statistics

Comment: According to the vertical scale in your plots, your bar chart represents approximately 4,000 observations.  Although a sample size of 25 is far too small to represent a Poisson-like distribution with any precision, a sample in which most bin counts are in the hundreds starts giving a good picture.  As a rule of thumb, the standard error in a histogram bar equals the square root of its count.

Comment: Yes, I should emphasize there's a difference between the distribution of the sample mean being roughly Normally distributed and the population mean being accurately estimated by the sample mean.